# Asymptotics for pairs of positive integers whose harmonic (resp. geometric) mean is an integer

Tags: analytic-number-theory, asymptotics

How does the cardinality of $$\{(a,b): 1 \leq a,b \leq n, \ 2ab/(a+b) \ \mbox{is an integer}\}$$ grow as a function of $n$? What about $$\{(a,b): 1 \leq a,b \leq n, \ \sqrt{ab} \ \mbox{is an integer}\}?$$ For $n=10$, $100$, $1000$, and $10000$ the two functions of $n$ are close and getting closer (in relative terms); one might even surmise that the ratio tends to 1.

For those who care, those ratios are $18/14 = 1.2857$, $310/272 = 1.1397$, $4344/3976 = 1.0926$, and $57296/52756 = 1.0861$. Numerators are for the geometric mean and denominators are for the harmonic mean. On the other hand, $10000$ is not very big, so the data from the previous sentence may not reflect the true asymptotic behavior of the two functions.

Comment: The $ab=c^2$ part at least is not hard: 
let $d = \gcd(a,b)$, so $(a,b) = (d \, x^2, d \, y^2)$
for some relatively prime $x,y$ both at most $(n/d)^{1/2}$.
There are about $(6/\pi^2) (n/d)$ such pairs, 
and summing over $d$ gives about $(6/\pi^2) n \log n$.
That's not too far from your numerical values: for $n=10^3,10^4$
it rounds to $4199, 55992$ respectively.

Comment: Oh, and $2ab/(a+b) = c$ is also a plane conic, so should have
the same asymptotic up to the constant factor, and given your calculations
for $n \leq 10^4$ I can believe that the constants are the same.

Comment: The formatting of this post is pretty awful in some views, but I don’t know how to fix it. I’ll see if I can find relevant info on recent changes to MathOverflow. In the meantime, if any kind person wants to fix the issues with my formatting, I’ll be grateful.

Comment: An ideal answer to my question (assuming that the ratio converges to 1) would include an analysis of the direction and rate of convergence.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[CORRECTED 8/28]

I think the asymptotic ratio is $(4/3)*\ln(2)\approx 0.924196$.

$$G(n) = (6/\pi^2)*n*\ln(n) + O(n)$$
$$H(n) = (8\ln(2)/\pi^2)*n*\ln(n) + O(n)$$

The proof for the geometric mean goes as Noam Elkies posted.

For the harmonic mean, we will first characterize "primitive" solutions: pairs $(a,b)$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $(a+b)|(2ab)$.

Let $r=p/q$ be a rational number in lowest terms. Then $(a,a*r)$ has integer harmonic mean iff $(p+q)|(2ap)$, which is true iff $a$ is a multiple of $(p+q)/\gcd(p+q,2)$. And we also need $a*r$ to be an integer, which means $q|a$. So we get a primitive solution iff $a=q(p+q)/\gcd(p+q,2)$.

So the primitive solutions are:

$(p(p+q),q(p+q))$ when $\gcd(p,q)=1$ and $p+q$ is odd,

$(p(p+q)/2,q(p+q)/2)$ when $\gcd(p,q)=1$ and $p+q$ is even.

Or, equivalently,

$(p*s, (s-p)*s)$ when $\gcd(p,s)=1$, $s$ is odd, $p<s$,

$(p*s/2, (s-p)*s/2)$ when $gcd(p,s)=1$, $s$ is even, $p<s$.

We will count all solutions bounded by $n$ by assuming $s/2<p<s$ (except $(p,s)=(1,2)$), and then multiplying by 2 for symmetry:

$$n+2 \int_{1}^{\sqrt{n}} \int_{p}^{\min(2p,n/p)} \frac{1}{2}\frac{8}{\pi^2}\frac{n}{ps} \,ds\,dp
+ 2 \int_{1}^{\sqrt{2n}} \int_{p}^{\min(2p,2n/p)} \frac{1}{2}\frac{4}{\pi^2}\frac{n}{ps/2} \,ds\,dp $$
$$ = n + \int_{1}^{\sqrt{n/2}} \int_{p}^{2p} \frac{8}{\pi^2}\frac{n}{ps} \,ds\,dp
  + \int_{\sqrt{n/2}}^{\sqrt{n}} \int_{p}^{n/p} \frac{8}{\pi^2}\frac{n}{ps} \,ds\,dp \\ $$
$$ + \int_{1}^{\sqrt{n}} \int_{p}^{2p} \frac{8}{\pi^2}\frac{n}{ps} \,ds\,dp
  + \int_{\sqrt{n}}^{\sqrt{2n}} \int_{p}^{2n/p} \frac{8}{\pi^2}\frac{n}{ps} \,ds\,dp $$
$$ \asymp n + (4\ln(2)/\pi^2)*n*\ln(n)
    + (2\ln(2)^2/\pi^2)*n $$
$$  + (4\ln(2)/\pi^2)*n*\ln(n)
    + (2\ln(2)^2/\pi^2)*n$$
$$ = (8\ln(2)/\pi^2)*n*\ln(n) + O(n) $$

(Note: the exact integrals should have $\lfloor n/(ps)\rfloor$ in place of $n/(ps)$, but this is bounded above by $n/(ps)$ and bounded below by $n/(ps)-1$, and we can compute both integrals and show that they are asymptotically equivalent.)

Comment: How closely does your asymptotic for harmonic means follow the numerics of OP?

Comment: Well, the ratio is decreasing, but not at a rate which would seem likely to reach 0.693. So that's unclear. I could have a calculation error, or a logical error. Happy for someone to check my work.

Comment: I think my answer is wrong. I computed more terms of G(n) and H(n):
$$G(10^k) = \{18, 310, 4344, 57296, 714036, 8540120, 99371160, 1133650428, \
12735999860\}$$
$$H(10^k) = \{14, 272, 3976, 52756, 656760, 7861028, 91547056, 1044839104, \
11742081244\}$$
$$H(10^k)/G(10^k) = \{0.777778, 0.877419, 0.915285, 0.920762, 0.919786, 0.920482, 0.921264, \
0.921659, 0.92196\}$$
I'm going to guess it's converging to $(4/3)*\ln(2)=0.924196$, i.e., $H(n) \asymp 8\ln(2)*n*\ln(n).$ I've probably got a factor of 2 error in one of the terms.

Comment: Indeed with that hint I found and corrected the mistake.